# .WAR file runs on one Tomcat server but not the other

Tags: java, mysql, spring, tomcat, tomcat8

I'm unable to deploy a web application on my Tomcat server. Strangely, it works fine on a second testing server I set up. I did my best to make the environments on both machines as similar as possible, and to deploy the application the same way. I'm not sure how to proceed with troubleshooting at this point.

Both servers are running `Tomcat/8.0.37` on `JVM 1.8.0_101-b13` with a MySQL backend (Version `14.14 Distrib 5.7.15 for Linux (x86_64) using EditLine wrapper`). The OS for both is Ubuntu 14.04, though they are hosted by different cloud providers. I have deployed the .WAR files on both servers through the Manager App's upload feature. On the non-working server, clicking Start yields the error **FAIL - Application at context path /mediaServer could not be started**. In Tomcat's `logs/catalina.out` file, I see this warning:

```
19-Sep-2016 20:45:29.239 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-1]
  org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose
Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call
  'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root
  WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Sep 19 20:45:29 UTC 2016]; root
  of context hierarchy
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext
  .getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:359)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext
  .doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:890)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext
  .close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:843)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext 
  (ContextLoader.java:579)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed
  (ContextLoaderListener.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop
  (StandardContext.java:4900)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal
  (StandardContext.java:5537)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:221)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:149)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1284)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:666)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:217)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
  (ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
  (ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter
  (CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
  (ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
  (ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
  (ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
  (ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter
  (SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
  (ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
  (ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke
  (StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke
  (StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke
  (AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process
  (RequestFilterValve.java:313)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:86)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke
  (AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process
  (AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1100)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process
  (AbstractProtocol.java:687)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

19-Sep-2016 20:45:29.249 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-5]     
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The  
  web application [mediaServer] appears to have started a thread named 
  [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is 
  very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver$1.run(NonRegisteringDriver.java:93)
```

I see no such warnings on the working server.

Not sure if it's relevant, but the working server's Tomcat manager shows the OS version as `3.13.0-30-generic`, whereas the non-working one shows `4.7.0-x86_64-linode72`.

Other details:

- I have two other .WAR files which are deployed and working fine on both servers.
- The MySQL database names, contents, and credentials are identical on both servers.

Edits:

- I have tried copying the .WAR file in question to the server and deploying it manually in the `webapps` directory. The issue persists and the full error log is here: http://sprunge.us/BKLg
- I have also deployed the .WAR file successfully on my local Windows machine and a remote Windows Server VM. The issue only occurs on this one Ubuntu VM.

Comment: check your application specific log file

Comment: Most likely, the real error is somewhere in the "followed shortly after" part - that is, after your first snippet, and before your second snippet.  The first snippet just says things went wrong; the second snippet is typical output when a Spring app shuts down unexpectedly; somewhere in between should be an exception that says exactly what went wrong.

Comment: @sidgate, I wasn't able to find one, do you know where it would be located?

Comment: The error seems to be from when shutting down the webapp or server. If it fails to unload properly you typically have to restart the server. Often you have to kill it, because the old process is still holding on to the port.

Comment: @coladict, after rebooting the server the issue has persisted.

Comment: Yes, but is it the same error message? This one only shows the problem that is caused by the original one.

Comment: This happens every time you deploy?  It seems like stop() is called right after start(), I see in the stack trace: LifeCycleBase.stop() is right after LifeCycleBase.start().  Do you have any other way to deploy, aside from the Tomcat manager app?  Is there any interesting output in catalina.out, above what you have posted?

Comment: @DavidMiller, I tried removing the apps from the `webapps` directory and deploying the .WAR file manually with no success. It happens every time I deploy. I've uploaded the full log here: http://sprunge.us/BKLg

Comment: Now we see the error: `java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class`.  Typically it means your webapp has access to multiple versions of the same class file.  From a quick search for IncompatibleClassChangeError, it happens mainly with drivers and infrastructure code (e.g. JSON libraries).  Can you examine the JARs provided by the Tomcat container (i.e. the Tomcat lib folder)?  And can you carefully review your war file dependencies?  Although I am guessing Tomcat's lib folder has some jars that are also in your war, since the war deploys cleanly in the other cloud provider.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good suggestion—I'll give it a try.

Comment: @ecliptica did you find any solution - was there a jar conflict after all?